# Replace multiple identical characters with a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Using Javascript, I want to replace:

`This is a test, please complete ____.`

with:

`This is a test, please complete %word%.`

The number of underlines isn't consistent, so I cannot just use something like `str.replace('_____', '%word%')`.

I've tried `str.replace(/(_)*/g, '%word%')` but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the capturing group, and make sure `_` repeats with `+` (at least one occurrence, matches as many `_`s as possible):

```js
const str = 'This is a test, please complete ____.';
console.log(
  str.replace(/_+/g, '%word%')
);
```

The regular expression

```
/(_)*/
```

means, in plain language: match zero or more underscores, which of course isn't what you're looking for. That will match *every* position in the string (except positions in the string between underscores).

Comment: Thank you, simpler than what I thought! I feared I had to use one of those complex lookahead expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a slightly different approach to this.  Instead of maintaining the sentence as you currently have it, instead maintain something like this:

```
This is the {$1} test, please complete {$2}.
```

When you want to *render* this sentence, use a regex replacement to replace the placeholders with underscores:

```js
var sentence = "This is the {$1} test, please complete {$2}.";
var show = sentence.replace(/\{\$\d+\}/g, "____");
console.log(show);
```

When you want to replace a given placeholder, you may also use a targeted regex replacement.  For example, to target the first placeholder you could use:

```js
var sentence = "This is the {$1} test, please complete {$2}.";
var show = sentence.replace(/\{\$1\}/g, "first");
console.log(show);
```

This is a fairly robust and scalable solution, and is more accurate than just doing a single blanket replacement of all underscores.